# cannot output a json encoded dict containing accents (noob inside)

Tags: python, json, utf-8

here is a fairly simple example wich is driving me nuts since a couple of days. Considering the following script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from json import dumps as json_dumps

machaine = u"une personne émérite"
print(machaine)

output = {}
output[1] = machaine
jsonoutput = json_dumps(output)
print(jsonoutput)
```

The result of this from cli:

```
une personne émérite
{"1": "une personne \u00e9m\u00e9rite"}
```

I don't understand why their such a difference between the two strings.
i have been trying all sorts of encode, decode etc but i can't seem to be able to find the right way to do it. Does anybody has an idea ?

Thanks in advance.
Matthieu

Comment: `é` has been encoded to `\u00e9` because it's not an ASCII character. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding is correct. Load it back in and print it, and you'll see the correct output:

```
>>> import json
>>> jsoninput = json.loads(jsonoutput)
>>> print jsoninput
{u'1': u'une personne \xe9m\xe9rite'}
>>> print jsoninput['1']
une personne émérite
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Marcelo Cantos's answer: `json.dumps()` returns a JSON-encoding, which is an *ASCII* string, starting with the character '{', and containing backslashes, quotes, etc. You have to decode it (e.g. with `json.loads()` to get back the actual dict with data.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import json

output = {1: u"une personne émérite"}
print output[1]

json_encoded = json.dumps(output)
print "Encoded: %s" % repr(json_encoded)

input = json.loads(json_encoded)
print input['1']
```

outputs:

```
une personne émérite
Encoded: '{"1": "une personne \\u00e9m\\u00e9rite"}'
une personne émérite
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would javascript deal with the encoded characters?

Comment: JS would work correctly. E.g. save this as a file and load in your browser, you should see the correct string (at least I do):

    <html><body><script>
        x = eval('({"1": "une personne \\u00e9m\\u00e9rite"})');
        document.write(x[1]);
    </script></body></html>

Comment: JSON encodings are not ASCII strings. They are Unicode strings, usually transmitted or stored as UTF-8.